# Partition of fluidRow() with two box()s?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to partition the fluid row into 65% and 35%.
65% portion will have 4 infoBox and 35% portion will have 1 image.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(dashboardHeader("aa"),
dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody(
mainPanel(
tabsetPanel(
tabPanel(
fluidRow(
box(width='65%', 
infoBox("Total visits", width = 4, icon = icon("compass"), color = 
"yellow"),
infoBox("Revisits", width = 4, icon = icon("compass"), color = "yellow"), 
infoBox("Uinique Registrations", width = 4,icon = icon("compass"), color = 
"yellow"),
infoBox("Avg. Visits per day", width = 4, icon = icon("compass"), color = 
"yellow") 
))))))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Can anyone help me out to build this structure, please?

Thank you.[image]

Comment: have you tried using `column()` inside of `fluidRow()`? That can help you build similar structure. Although it uses grid system, you can get similar result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using `column()`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 8,
      box(
        width = 12,
        infoBox(
          "Total visits",
          width = 6,
          icon = icon("compass"),
          color =
            "yellow"
        ),
        infoBox(
          "Revisits",
          width = 6,
          icon = icon("compass"),
          color = "yellow"
        ),
        infoBox(
          "Uinique Registrations",
          width = 6,
          icon = icon("compass"),
          color =
            "yellow"
        ),
        infoBox(
          "Avg. Visits per day",
          width = 6,
          icon = icon("compass"),
          color =
            "yellow"
        )

      )
    ), column(width = 4, box(
      "myImage", width = 12, height = "233px"
    ))
  ))
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

For further information please see the [Shiny application layout guide](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html).